# SQL to select email and max id

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have a table which records email addresses for newsletter purposes. When someone subscribes it sets a subscribe ind to 'Y' and there is an incremental id. When someone subscribes/unsubscribes, I need to select all table entries for the email address, but then select based on the highest id.

Once I have this info I can use the subscribe ind to see if they are subscribed or not. I have been trying to figure this one out but without success. I am trying something like:

**mysql_query**

```
SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE email=$email and 
id=(select max(id) from newsletter)
```

Should I be doing something else?

Comment: Maybe you could explain your table design a little bit more in detail, for me it's not really clear..

Comment: When the user subscribes or unsubscibes to emails, don't they have a flag in the user or userprofile type record?

Comment: The indicator is used rather than deleting the record from the table. While a new entry is created every time, I need to select the most current row (by id) for the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT col1,col2,max(id)
FROM newsletter 
WHERE email=$email
group by col1,col2
```

**EDIT**

```
select *
from newsletter 
WHERE email=$email
and id in (select max(id) from newsletter group by email)
```

Comment: I don't see the point of doing max(id) here as it returns all the rows e.g:
email1 106
email1 107.

Can I just return the 107?

Comment: I think it is more optimal "group by" with "having" do you think?

Comment: @DavidMiró What if i want to select all columns?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by email:

```
SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE email=$email and 
id=(select max(id) from newsletter group by email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id, email
FROM newsletter 
GROUP BY email
HAVING email=$email
```

Comment: Optimal if you do not need other columns. Thanks @Luv